# Azure translator api invocation error in postman

Tags: azure, postman

We are trying to build a translator application.We obtained the azure cognitive services subscription and tried to invoke the api endpoint using postman.We are getting the following error.Please help us out on this.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36XKF.png)

Comment: What body and headers are you sending?

Comment: Body:[{'Text':'Hello, what is your name?'}]

Comment: Headers: Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:" " ,Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region:eastus Content-Type: application/json

Comment: The key you have in your image is meant to be secret. If you haven't already, regenerate your keys.